# Bad cast not caught after dynamic casting

Tags: c++

How is it possible that I pass the try succesfully with a non `const Triangle` pointer?

```
const Triangle *prim;
const GeometricPrimitive *gp;
try {
    gp = dynamic_cast<const GeometricPrimitive*>(primitives[edges[axis][j].primNum].GetPtr());
    prim = dynamic_cast<const Triangle*>((gp->shape).GetPtr());
}
catch (std::bad_cast& bc) {
    continue;
}
```

[image]

```
template <typename T> class Reference {
public:
    ...
    T *operator->() { return ptr; }
    const T *operator->() const { return ptr; }
    operator bool() const { return ptr != NULL; }
    const T *GetPtr() const { return ptr; }
private:
    T *ptr;
};
```

Edit:
[image]

Comment: `dynamic_cast` throws exception only when you cast to unrelated reference type, in case of pointers it returns `nullptr`

Comment: And your new image basically confirms @PiotrS.'s comment.

Comment: @PiotrS. so the null value (see edit) is not a default debugging value (for unitialised variables) and will also be there in a release version?

Comment: @Matthias as long as RTTI is enabled in release version, yes, it will be nullptr as well if dynamic_cast fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantics of `dynamic_cast` are described in §5.2.7/8:

> If `C` is the class type to which `T` points or refers, the run-time
>   check logically executes as follows:
>
> — If, in the most derived object
>   pointed (referred) to by `v`, `v` points (refers) to a public base
>   class subobject of a `C` object, and if only one object of type `C` is
>   derived from the subobject pointed (referred) to by `v` the result
>   points (refers) to that `C` object.
>
> — Otherwise, if `v` points (refers) to a public base class subobject
>   of the most derived object, and the type of the most derived object
>   has a base class, of type `C`, that is unambiguous and public, the
>   result points (refers) to the `C` subobject of the most derived
>   object.
>
> — Otherwise, the run-time check *fails*.

And paragraph 9:

> The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the **null pointer
>   value** of the required result type. A failed cast to reference type
>   throws `std::bad_cast` (18.7.2).

<sup>Note: you should probably include `<typeinfo>` for `std::badcast`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`bad_cast` will occur only when you are casting reference:
Try something like this:

```
Triangle prim;
GeometricPrimitive gp;
try {
    gp = dynamic_cast<const GeometricPrimitive &>(*(primitives[edges[axis][j].primNum].GetPtr()));

    prim = dynamic_cast<const Triangle &>(*((gp->shape).GetPtr()));

}
catch (std::bad_cast& bc) {
    continue;
}
```